# Can I achieve this layout with Masonry?

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

[image]

I am trying like this:

```
.grid {
  width: 99%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.grid a, .grid .grid-sizer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.grid a.wx2, .grid .grid-sizer.wx2 {
  width: 45%;
}
.grid a.hx2, .grid .grid-sizer.hx2 {
  padding-bottom: 66%;
}
.grid a.wx2.hx2, .grid .grid-sizer.wx2.hx2 {
  padding-bottom: 33%;
}
```

And

```
$(function () {
    $('.grid').masonry({
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 10
    });
});
```

but It's not using the full width avaliable,

Any idea what I'm missing?

See jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/6dL7x8uk/1/

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can.
The fiddle is missing a lot of things.
I would do it like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="children">
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/ZbvVmX

Comment: I don't think you have included the right link? It doesn't look like a fix for my issue..

Comment: Yea, it is an entirely different approach. But same results, i will have a look  how to do it with your approach when i get home. Thought it does not matter how to achieve it, as long the result is the same.

Comment: I don't know, I just don't see the resemblance. when you post an answer in Stack overflow... i has to be more clear, perhaps it had to be a comment instead?